# How do I pass data with intent in onResponse method

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to pass variable "points" with intent to another activity. When I try to do this inside onRensponse method getExtrasString retrurns null. And If I try to do this in the onClick method that calls UserSingIn the variable "points" is empty. Is there a way to pass it with intent in onResponse or wait in onClick till I get this data?

```
private void userSingIn(){

    String cardId = editcard.getText().toString().trim();


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIUrl.DETAILS_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    final User user = new User();
    user.setCardId(cardId);

    Call<Result> call = service.loginUser(
            user.getCardId()

    );

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body().getPoints(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            userpass = response.body().getPassword();
            points = response.body().getPoints();


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `getExtrasString`?

Comment: I tried in main body on the activity and in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Create context variable and assign it this in onCreate

`Context context;
context = this.`

then create intent like this

`Intent i = new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class);`

Answer (score 0):

I woyld recommend to use debugger, put breakpoints on the code that puts value in the intent and check if it actually has the String  that has value of variable "points".